# React Native - run-ios - React Packager process fails due to thinking I am running io.js version 1.6.2

Tags: react-native, homebrew, homebrew-cask, react-native-ios

I am attempting to start developing my first ever React Native application.  I've installed the react-native-cli and ran the command react-native ios-run.  The build is successful, and the simulator seems to boot up fine.  However, a second terminal appears with the following message:

You are currently running io.js v1.6.2.

React Native runs on Node 4.0 or newer. There are several ways to
   upgrade Node.js depending on your preference.

nvm:       nvm install node && nvm alias default node
Homebrew:  brew unlink iojs; brew install node
Installer: download the Mac .pkg from https://nodejs.org/
About Node.js:   https://nodejs.org                                    Follow along at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2545
~
Process terminated. Press  to close the window

**I have tried:**

uninstalling and reinstalling node via Homebrew.
node -v = 7.3.0

brew unlink iojs
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/iojs

nvm install node && nvm alias default node
doesn't change anything.

navigated to /usr/local/bin and uninstalled iojs
iojs -v 
-bash: iojs: command not found

brew update: no changes to formulae

brew doctor: nothing besides usual warnings

brew prune: nothing

brew cask uninstall iojs
Error: iojs is not installed

Help is appreciated here.  I am at a loss to understand how I can be running io.js v1.6.2 when I'm pretty certain iojs is not installed on my machine.  But perhaps I am missing something...cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.  Uninstalled all versions of node / deleted any node or node_modules folders from /usr/local/lib/.

Also nvm uninstall iojs --force.

Downloaded node from  https://nodejs.org/en/download/​.  After all that, it worked.  I'll leave this here for anyone else who encounters this problem!